# assertEquals controller.action() return null....!

Tags: grails, integration-testing, spock

```
     class ProjectDashBoardController {
/*
 * This method is used to display project implementation's overview.
 */
def check() {
    render "Hello"
}
```

and this is my integration test

```
  package com.spock

 import grails.plugin.spock.IntegrationSpec

class ProjectDashBoardControllerIntegrationSpec extends IntegrationSpec {

ProjectDashBoardController controller = new ProjectDashBoardController()

def cleanup() {
}

void "test check action"() {

    when:
    controller.check()

    then:
    controller.check()
    assertEquals "/dashboard/index", controller.response.redirectedUrl


}
```

}

as per the, then condition the test should fail since action render but instead it showing such error
No signature of method: com.itxchg.ProjectDashBoardControllerIntegrationSpec.assertEquals() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, null) values: [/dashboard/index, null]

Comment: Have a look at the edit to Graeme's answer. Also accept answer if it was helpful. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spock doesn't have an `assertEquals` method, you should use regular Groovy power asserts, although `assert` is implicit in `then` block when spock is used:

```
 assert "/dashboard/index" == controller.response.redirectedUrl
```

In your case though you do have have a redirect scenario to test. What actually should be tested is that the response consists the rendered text:

```
void "test check action"() {
    when:
    controller.check()

    then:
    // Note there is no need to explicitly specify assert in then block
    // Assertion is implicit
    controller.response.text == "Hello"
}
```

Comment: Indeed the action does return null, the render method has no return value. You have to assert the value of "response.text" since the render method writes to the response